# Integrate SSO for a 3rd party enterprise application

Tags: azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, azureportal

I want to integrate SSO in my client's azure AD with a 3rd party enterprise application.
We dont have access to the backend of the 3rd party appliction which is basically a SAAS. So the 3rd party app team asked us to setup SSO in azure ad portal and share with them the signin url and IDP metadata.
Which option I should choose in azure ad portal to do this:
enterprise application or app registration?

Answer (score 0):

The way you can add your application to azure ad is completely depending on the SSO type you are using for your application.

1. If the application was registered using App registrations, then the single sign-on capability is configured to use OIDC OAuth by default.
2. If you register through Enterprise application, you will be having option to setup SAML based, password based authentication types.

Here is the reference doc to setup SAML based SSO [SAML based SSO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/add-application-portal-setup-sso)

If you want to setup OIDC based SSO you can use this [OIDC SSO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/add-application-portal-setup-oidc-sso)
Quickstart

Many apps have already been pre-configured to work with Azure AD. These apps are listed in the gallery of apps that you can browse when you add an app to your Azure AD tenant.
Here is the reference for integrating SAAS application with azure ad [SAAS App integration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/saas-apps/tutorial-list).